# pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database failed: FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: postgresql, database-backup, psql

I'm trying to backup my Postgres DB to another server but I keep getting denied access.

my pg_hba.conf file looks like this:

```
# DO NOT DISABLE!
# If you change this first entry you will need to make sure that the
# database superuser can access the database using some other method.
# Noninteractive access to all databases is required during automatic
# maintenance (custom daily cronjobs, replication, and similar tasks).
#
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

If I change the postgres setting from PEER to TRUST, i can backup the code but the web site can no longer access the database (something about SSL error, which I know isn't the issue).

When I leave it as is, PEER, the server works - php can access the db - but I get error while trying to run the backup:

root> pg_dump -U postgres tablename > test.sql

.pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "tablename" failed: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres".

PHP Apache Web site uses appropriate username and password.

Backup script looks like this: pg_dump -U postgres tablename > test.sql

how can I satisfy both the web site and the backup script so I can run both?

Entire script attempted is this:
ssh SERVER "pg_dump -U postgres tablename| gzip -c" > /backup/sqlbackup.sql.gz

taken from Server Fault: [ssh remote command-fu](https://serverfault.com/questions/39931/ssh-remote-command-fu)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your PHP Apache web site works with `peer`, keep this, and let's deal with it.

**1. First Method :**

As authentication is peer based, you have to specify the hostname (usually localhost) using `-h` option :

```
ssh server "pg_dump -h localhost -U postgres | gzip -c" >/backup/sqlbackup.sql.gz
```

The main issue here is that you will be prompted for the postgres user password. It is a problem for backups automation .

You can refer to [this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/libpq-pgpass.html) to avoid to be prompted for the password. But i will describe :

1. Create an hidden file named `.pgpass` in `$HOME`
2. Perform a `chmod 600 .pgpass`
3. Edit file `.pgpass` and add this line : `localhost:5432:postgres:postgres:password`

---

**2. Second Method :**

You could add a specific role for backups and trust it.

Create the backup role in Postgres :

```
CREATE ROLE backup WITH LOGIN SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'password'
```

Edit file `pg_hba.conf`, add role `backup` and `trust` it :

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer
local   all             backup                                  trust
```

Restart `postgresql`

Then you should be able to run backup with the following :

```
ssh server "pg_dump -U backup postgres | gzip -c" >/backup/sqlbackup.sql.gz
```

Comment: If the `-h localhost` is given, `pg_dump` will prompt for a password for the user `postgres`. But if this user relies on a peer connection, it actually doesn't have a password. How would you bypass this?